# Google+ Interactive shares on android are broken in version 4.2.4.58179886

Tags: google-plus, share, interactive

Latest version 4.2.4.58179886 of Google+ for Android is not showing new call-to-action buttons of Interactive Shares.

The scenario is as follows:

1. Create an interactive with call-to-action
2. Open Google+ app
3. Notice that there's no button in the share item.

Is there a workaround or if you're from Google+ Dev Team - is a fix planned?
Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Note that I've tested this with the official sample app that was provided with the Android SDK.

Observation: The interactive share works correctly on Google+ 4.2.3.56698342

Thanks beforehand. Max.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug in the Google+ app that will be fixed shortly after the upcoming holidays. Currently there are no workarounds, but you can continue to write interactive posts and they will show correctly in the stream for on iOS and web. New and old interactive posts will display correctly again with the next Google+ app update.

Answer (score 1):

If you recompile your app using the latest version of Google Play Services 4.2: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/google-play-services-42.html then interactive posts will show up.