# Google Plus deep link sharing From Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I've ran into a problem with Google+ sharing recently.

What I want to do is to share a deep link to my app section using a URI path as described  [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/deep-link#2_choosing_a_deep-link_identifier). And it used to work - a post with a link appeared in G+ and opened my app DeepLinkActivity when I clicked on it. But suddenly it stopped working. G+ sharing happens without any errors, i. e, post appears, but clicking on it does nothing. I just can't figure out what's going on here. I do as described in documentation exactly, but it just seems like G+ client doesn't fire the intent. Deep linking is enabled in dev. console for client id of course.

The code is:

```
PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setContentDeepLinkId("pear2://one/1/two/2", getString(R.string.app_name), categoryName + ": " + name, Uri.parse("uri to image"));
builder.setText("Blah Blah");
return builder.getIntent();
```

And then just startActivityForResult. Once again, sharing works perfectly fine, but the link does nothing :(

Any help please?

Comment: Does this happen across all devices, and which versions of the Google+ app and Google Play services are involved?

Comment: Hello, Google Play services is at 4.0.30, but I tried updating to latest to no effect. Google+ app is at 4.3.1.63038142. Problem is reproducible on my Nexus 10 4.4.2, Galaxy Nexus 4.3 and rooted SGS4 with custom Google Play edition 4.4.2.

Comment: Which version of google play services lib was the app built against (eg which version from sdk manager)?

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30' and the current installed version of Google Play services is 4.3.25

Comment: and sdk manager has version 16

Comment: I have updated Google Play services SDK to latest and still no change. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you share a post publicly with a deeplink, and paste the URL in here?

Comment: Hi, yes, here is the link. https://plus.google.com/112224729690591769589/posts/di12sCFbFyD

Comment: Another observation is that if I actually set setContentUrl to anything non-empty (e. g. my app Google Play listing, the deep link actually starts working). But that's not what I need because at the moment I don't have a web content and it overrides the title and description I set. I think this is a bug.

Comment: My problem is suspiciously similar to this SO question btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695264/deep-link-shares-to-google-but-link-does-nothing

Comment: Can you try doing the .setType("text/plain") and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Hi. Nope, no difference. I have even tried calling them in the same sequence as in documentation. Still no difference. Deep link works ONLY if setContentUrl is called with something non-empty.

Comment: Thanks - I'll pass this back to some of the engineers and get back to you.

Comment: I have the same problem, but it's not working even with using setContentUrl with an arbitrary value. I wouldn't mind that contingency. Would you mind sharing the code for a working Deep Link intent? thanks